# jwt и запросы к карте(osm, geoserver)

Tags: request, openstreetmap, jwt, geoserver

Сталкивался кто-нибудь с такой проблемой: есть фронт, есть rest сервис и есть картографический сервис(geoserver), так же авторизация(jwt) через rest сервис. Но в итоге картографический сервис крутится отдельно и запросы ему уходят без ключа, следовательно как бы не защищенные.

Суть вопроса: стоит ли при каждом запросе тайла (256*256px) так же отправлять еще и ключи, ведь выйдет в два раза больше запросов из-за pre-fligth запросов, следовательно скорость загрузки карты упадет. Может кто делал такое или сталкивался?

Comment: Как у вас связаны jwt и preflight запросы? jwt это же просто подписанный json..

Comment: `Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization` вот так и связаны, брузер автоматически делает из это запроса сложный. @Darth

Comment: ну так положите ваш jwt не в хедер, а еще куда нибудь. в GET или POST параметр например.

Comment: @Darth сервис написан сторонними разработчиками(geoserver), зпросы отправляются при помощи openlayers. Если вы знаете как парсить jwt на geoserver, буду очень признателен. Иначе обновлять его потом станет проблемой, верно мыслю?